# Wrong values when reading integers from file

Tags: c++

I asked a similar question some weeks ago, but I got stuck, and didn't really know if I didn't make any other mistakes.

I can relatively clearly tell what I am fighting with now.

I am trying re-write a VB6 function in C++.
The difficult line is this one:

```
vector<int>vIntegerValues;

vIntegerValues.resize(iCountIntegers);

fseek(iReadFile, uFromBytePos * sizeof(int), SEEK_CUR);

size_t readElements = fread(&vIntegerValues[0], sizeof(int), iCountIntegers, iReadFile);
```

My VB6 version is this:

```
Dim vIntegerValues() As Integer

ReDim vIntegerValues(0 To iCountIntegers)

Get #iReadFile, uFromBytePos, vIntegerValues()
```

However the C++ function fills up the integer vector with data that is not as expected.

For example in VB6 the first values are:
0,0,2,2,0,-2,0,-2,0,2,0,0,-2,

And in C++ the first values are 
131074, -131072, -131072, 131072, 0, 65534

Can somebody help when he sees where I go wrong?
Thank you very much.

ps: I don't know in advance what the size of the vector vIntegerValues will be, so please do not suggest anything with a fixed vector. This is where I would get stuck.

Comment: if you're using C++, why are you using `fseek` and `fread` instead of the [`iostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) library?

Comment: Is the file a text file or a binary file? Is it opened in text or binary mode?

Comment: Looks like a different definition of `int` is being used - what is `sizeof(int)` on your platform - is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: I open the file this way:  FILE* iReadFile; iReadFile = fopen(filename.c_str(),"rb");

Comment: I am using fseek and fread instead of iostream because I am not experienced with iostream, and I am afraid of wrecking my code up even more. The file is a binary file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your VB6 `Integer`s are 16-bit words. Use `int16_t` (or `short int` on some platforms, including yours :) to get the same thing in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the size of the numbers, you are reading 16 bit numbers into 32 bit fields. Define your data type as `short int` and modify your code accordingly.